# Код не выводит ничего, может ошибка в функциях?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот мой код. Я только начал программировать и решил сделать шифратор и дешифратор азбуки Морзе, но при вводе текста и shifr он ничего не выводит, но должен выводить шифрованный текст. Мне нужна подсказка. Заранее спасибо

```
text = (input('Введите текст или шифр Морзе(через пробел):').encode('utf8'))
alf = ['А', 'Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д','Е','Ж','З','И','Й','К','Л','М','Н','О','П','Р','С','Т','У','Ф','Х','Ц','Ч','Ш','Щ','Ъ','Ы','Ь','Э','Ю','Я']
mrz = ['•− ', '-••• ', '•−− ','−−• ','−•• ','• ','•••− ','−−•• ','•• ','•−−− ','−•− ','•−•• ','−− ','−• ','−−− ','•−−• ','•−• ','••• ','− ','••− ','••−• ','•••• ','−•−• ','−−−• ','−−−− ','−−•− ','−−•−− ','−•−− ','−••− ','••−•• ','••−− ','•−•− ']
#•−
def shifr():
    while True:
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if text == alf[i]:
                print(mrz[i])

def deshifr():
    while True:
        for i in range(len(text)):
            if text == mrz[i]:
                print(alf[i])

ask = (input('Что делаем сейчас? \n Для перевода в текст, напиши slovo \n Для перевода в шифр Морзе, напиши shifr \n Если хочешь просто уйти, напиши close\n'))
if ask == '+':
    deshifr()
elif ask == '-':
    shifr()

input()
```

Comment: в этом моменте забыл поменять + и - на slovo и shifr
```
if ask == '+':
    deshifr()
elif ask == '-':
    shifr()
```

Comment: вводишь shift или slovo, а проверяешь на + и -. После того, как исправишь, все равно не будет правильно работать, потому что неправильный алгоритм.

Comment: а что не так в алгоритме?

Comment: Все не так. Абсолютно все.

Comment: И вот сейчас я чувствую напряжение в зоне бикини

Comment: То есть мне лучше использовать что-то другое, не массив?

Comment: Да почему же, если правильно, то можно и массив (т.е. список).

Comment: Но в чем тогда у меня ошибка, я не понимаю

Comment: ну как минимум что while(True) - это бесконечный цикл, который требует остановки, а вы его не останавливаете

Comment: ну а второе, я бы использовал словарь, т.е ключ - значение

Answer (score 1):

```py
de = {'А': '•− ', 'Б': '-••• ', 'В': '•−− ', 'Г': '−−• ', 'Д': '−•• ', 'Е': '• ', 'Ж': '•••− ', 'З': '−−•• ', 'И': '•• ', 'Й': '•−−− ', 'К': '−•− ', 'Л': '•−•• ', 'М': '−− ', 'Н': '−• ', 'О': '−−− ', 'П': '•−−• ', 'Р': '•−• ', 'С': '••• ', 'Т': '− ', 'У': '••− ', 'Ф': '••−• ', 'Х': '•••• ', 'Ц': '−•−• ', 'Ч': '−−−• ', 'Ш': '−−−− ', 'Щ': '−−•− ', 'Ъ': '−−•−− ', 'Ы': '−•−− ', 'Ь': '−••− ', 'Э': '••−•• ', 'Ю': '••−− ', 'Я': '•−•− '}
en = {'•− ': 'А', '-••• ': 'Б', '•−− ': 'В', '−−• ': 'Г', '−•• ': 'Д', '• ': 'Е', '•••− ': 'Ж', '−−•• ': 'З', '•• ': 'И', '•−−− ': 'Й', '−•− ': 'К', '•−•• ': 'Л', '−− ': 'М', '−• ': 'Н', '−−− ': 'О', '•−−• ': 'П', '•−• ': 'Р', '••• ': 'С', '− ': 'Т', '••− ': 'У', '••−• ': 'Ф', '•••• ': 'Х', '−•−• ': 'Ц', '−−−• ': 'Ч', '−−−− ': 'Ш', '−−•− ': 'Щ', '−−•−− ': 'Ъ', '−•−− ': 'Ы', '−••− ': 'Ь', '••−•• ': 'Э', '••−− ': 'Ю', '•−•− ': 'Я'}

def shifr():
    text = (input('Введите текст или шифр Морзе(через пробел):'))
    word = ''
    for letter in text:
        word += de[letter]
    print(word)

def deshifr():
    text = (input('Введите текст или шифр Морзе(через пробел):').encode('utf8'))
    word = ''
    for letter in text:
        word += en[letter]
    print(word)

ask = input()
if ask == 'out':
    deshifr()
elif ask == 'in':
    shifr()
```

быренько накидал, робит только для слов(не предложений)

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант работает с целыми предложениями.
Обратите внимание, что в словаре для расшифровки буквы азбуки Морзе идут без пробелов на конце, это сделано для того, чтобы была возможность сплитовать слова в строке по пробелу. Также код не падает если введены буквы нижнего или разных регистров.

```
de = {'А': '•− ', 'Б': '-••• ', 'В': '•−− ', 'Г': '−−• ', 'Д': '−•• ', 'Е': '• ', 'Ж': '•••− ', 'З': '−−•• ', 'И': '•• ', 'Й': '•−−− ', 'К': '−•− ', 'Л': '•−•• ', 'М': '−− ', 'Н': '−• ', 'О': '−−− ', 'П': '•−−• ', 'Р': '•−• ', 'С': '••• ', 'Т': '− ', 'У': '••− ', 'Ф': '••−• ', 'Х': '•••• ', 'Ц': '−•−• ', 'Ч': '−−−• ', 'Ш': '−−−− ', 'Щ': '−−•− ', 'Ъ': '−−•−− ', 'Ы': '−•−− ', 'Ь': '−••− ', 'Э': '••−•• ', 'Ю': '••−− ', 'Я': '•−•− '}
en = {'•−': 'А', '-•••': 'Б', '•−−': 'В', '−−•': 'Г', '−••': 'Д', '•': 'Е', '•••−': 'Ж', '−−••': 'З', '••': 'И', '•−−−': 'Й', '−•−': 'К', '•−••': 'Л', '−−': 'М', '−•': 'Н', '−−−': 'О', '•−−•': 'П', '•−•': 'Р', '•••': 'С', '−': 'Т', '••−': 'У', '••−•': 'Ф', '••••': 'Х', '−•−•': 'Ц', '−−−•': 'Ч', '−−−−': 'Ш', '−−•−': 'Щ', '−−•−−': 'Ъ', '−•−−': 'Ы', '−••−': 'Ь', '••−••': 'Э', '••−−': 'Ю', '•−•−': 'Я'}


def code():
    text = input('Введите текст, который хотите зашифровать:\n')
    for word in text.split():
        x = ''
        for letter in word.upper():
            x += de[letter]
        print(x, end=' ')
    print()


def encode():
    text = input('Введите текст, который хотите расшифровать:\n')
    for word in text.split('  '):
        x = ''
        for letter in word.split():
            x += en[letter]
        print(x, end=' ')
    print()


def main():
    x = input('Шифровать (1), Расшифровать (2)\n')
    if x == '1':
        code()
    elif x == '2':
        encode()
    y = input('Повторить? да(1) нет (2)\n')
    if y == '1':
        main()
    elif y == '2':
        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Тест:

```
Шифровать (1), Расшифровать (2)
1
Введите текст, который хотите зашифровать:
привет как твои дела
•−−• •−• •• •−− • −  −•− •− −•−  − •−− −−− ••  −•• • •−•• •−  
Повторить? да(1) нет (2)
1
Шифровать (1), Расшифровать (2)
2
Введите текст, который хотите расшифровать:
•−−• •−• •• •−− • −  −•− •− −•−  − •−− −−− ••  −•• • •−•• •−
ПРИВЕТ КАК ТВОИ ДЕЛА 
Повторить? да(1) нет (2)
```

Можно еще заморочиться, добавить знаки препинания в словарь, например.

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Vatth не за что) Можете отметить ответ как правильный, если вам подходит